# Image processing for video game on Android

Tags: android

I have the following question, recently I started with the study of Android and for some reason my research approach to development with GLES (OpenGL ES) thinking it was the only way of making application that is out of control that comes with the sdk standard they are made for it to be controlled.

Now I have been looking at the examples that comes with the SDK (Jetboy, LunarLander, etc) and I realize that use the method specifications drawBitMap canvas to display the images on the canvas.

I believe striking but still does not give the performance I expected (do not know if it's because I'm working in emulator) but not fluid.

know a form / technique / framework / library for this kind of development

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My favorite library for image processing in Android is cocos2d for android - http://code.google.com/p/cocos2d-android/ , it's more than image processing but also include many functionality.